# im newbie in matlab. so i need help. im try do this coding but have this error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, handwriting-recognition

```
I = imread('data1.jpg')
[p3, p4] = size(I);
q1 = 50; % size of the crop box
i3_start = floor((p3-q1)/2); % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i3_stop = i3_start + q1;

i4_start = floor((p4-q1)/2);
i4_stop = i4_start + q1;

I = I(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop, :);
figure ,imshow(I);
```

I have run this code and get this error " Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

> Error in ==> croptry at 10 I = I(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop,
>   :);"

Can anybody help me to fix this error? I want to crop image at the center

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably due to the way you call the functin `size`.

If the matrix `I` in which you load the image is tri-dimensional (N x M x K), you have to call `size` this way:

```
[p3, p4, p5] = size(I)
```

that is, by adding an additional parameter (in that case "p5").

If you call `size` as:

```
[p3, p4] = size(I)
```

p4 will be set to the product of the second and third dimension of your matrix `I`

**Updated code**

```
I = imread('pdb_img_1.jpg');
% Modified call to "size"
% [p3, p4] = size(I)
[p3, p4, p5] = size(I)
% Increased the size of the "crop box"
q1 = 150; % size of the crop box
i3_start = floor((p3-q1)/2) % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i3_stop = i3_start + q1

i4_start = floor((p4-q1)/2)
i4_stop = i4_start + q1

I = I(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop, :);
figure
imshow(I)
```

**Original Image**

[image]

**Cropped Image**
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you so much because help me with to fix this error. it works. thanks you

Comment: You're welcome! Happy I've been of use to you. Perhaps You might want to accept the answer to close the questione :-)

Comment: @user5405704 Consider accepting the answer as valid ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @il_raffa ive been use noise remover to smoothing the image, but i don't know the coding. can you help me?